# How to upload a image in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am unable to upload a image in the destination folder in codeigniter, I created one controller under the controller/admin folder with a name called site. And I added one model under the model folder with a name called model_view, and finally I created one view in the view folder with a name called view_addsite. And I created one table in the mysql with a name called sitesettings and 14 columns are added in that table. Problem hear is all fields are added in the table except image. please find the code.

```
           controller(site)::
           ===========
        public function add()
          { 

        $datte = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
       if(!$this->input->post('buttonSubmit'))
         {
          $data['message'] = '';
            $this->load->view('admin/view_addsite', $data);
        }
         else
         {
           //$this->load->library('form_validation');
           if($this->form_validation->run('addsite'))
            {   
                    $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
                  $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
                 $config['max_width']    = '2048';
                 $config['max_height']   = '2048';
                  $this->load->library('upload', $config);

               $title = $this->input->post('title');

            $name = $this->input->post('name');
            $admin = $this->input->post('admin');
            $mail = $this->input->post('mail');
            $phone = $this->input->post('phone');
            $contact=$this->input->post('contact');
            $fb=$this->input->post('fb');
            $tw=$this->input->post('tw');
            $yt=$this->input->post('yt');
            $in=$this->input->post('in');
            $gp=$this->input->post('gp');
            $ft=$this->input->post('ft');
            $this->upload->do_upload('image');
        $data = $this->upload->data('image');
        $image= $data['file_name'];
             $this>model_site>
                insert($title,$image,$name,$admin,$mail,
            $phone,$contact,$fb,$tw,$yt,$in,$gp,$ft);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','site Successfully 
          Created.');
            redirect(base_url('admin/site'));
        }
        else
        {
            $data['message'] = validation_errors();
            $this->load->view('admin/view_addsite', $data);
        }
         }
         }


             Model(model_site)::
             ===================


              public function  
             insert($title,$image,$name,$admin,$mail,$phone,$contact,
              $fb,$tw,$yt,$in,$gp,$ft)
                 {
               $data = array(
         'admintitle' => $title,
         'logo' => $image,
         'fromname' => $name,
          'adminemail'=> $admin,
          'receivemail' => $mail,
          'phonenumber' => $phone,
          'contactaddress' => $contact,
          'facebook' => $fb,
          'twitter'=>$tw,
          'youtube' => $yt,
          'instagram' => $in,
          'googleplus' => $gp,
          'footer' => $ft,
        );
           $this->db->insert('sitesettings', $data); 

                         }


                 view(view_addsite)::
                    ===================

                    <!-- page content -->
            <div class="right_col" role="main">
            <div class="">
                <div class="page-title">
              <div class="title_left">
             <h3>Sitesettings</h3>
             </div>
               </div><div class="clearfix"></div>
                <hr>
                   <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                 <div class="x_panel">
                <div class="x_title">
                    <h2>Add a new Site</h2>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                        <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-
               chevron-up"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close">
                </i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="x_content">
                    <label><?php echo $message; ?></label>
                    <form method="post">

                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                    AdminPage Title : <input class="form-control" 
                    placeholder="Admin Title" name="title" id="title"  
                      type="text"  ><span id="user-availability-status">
                         </span>

                            <div class="form-group">

                       Select image to upload:
                          <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" 
                        id="fileToUpload">&nbsp; 

                   </form>
                 <div class="form-group">
                     From Name : <input class="form-control" 
                 placeholder="Form Title" name="name" id="name" type="text" 
                 ><span id="user-availability-status"></span>

                              <div class="form-group">
               Admin Email Address : <input class="form-control" 
                   placeholder="Admin Email" name="admin" id="admin" 
                         type="text" onBlur="checkAvailability()" ><span 
                  id="user-availability-status"></span>

                              <div class="form-group">
                Receive Mail Address for Contact Us Form : <input 
                    class="form-control" placeholder="Receive Email" 
               name="mail" id="mail" type="text" 
               onBlur="checkAvailability()" ><span id="user-availability-
                status"></span>
                            </div>
                              <div class="form-group">       
                  Phone number: <input class="form-control" 
                   placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone" id="phone" 
                  type="text" onBlur="checkAvailability()" ><span id="user-
                  availability-status"></span>
                            </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                Contact Adress : <input class="form-control" 
                  placeholder="Contact Address" name="contact" id="contact" 
                     type="text" onBlur="checkAvailability()" ><span 
                   id="user-availability-status"></span>
                            </div>
              <div class="form-group">
               Facebook : <input class="form-control" placeholder="Facebook" 
              name="fb" id="fb" type="text" onBlur="checkAvailability()" >
               <span id="user-availability-status"></span>
                            </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                Twitter : <input class="form-control" placeholder="Twitter" 
                name="tw" id="tw" type="text" onBlur="checkAvailability()" >
                     <span id="user-availability-status"></span>
                            </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                  Youtube : <input class="form-control" 
               placeholder="Youtube" name="yt" id="yt" type="text" 
               onBlur="checkAvailability()" ><span id="user-availability-
               status"></span>
                            </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                Instagram : <input class="form-control" 
              placeholder="Instagram" name="in" id="in" type="text" 
               onBlur="checkAvailability()" ><span id="user-availability-
               status"></span>
                            </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                    Google Plus: <input class="form-control" 
                placeholder="Google Plus" name="gp" id="gp" type="text" 
               onBlur="checkAvailability()" ><span id="user-availability-
                status"></span>
                            </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                     Footer: <input class="form-control" 
                              placeholder="Footer" name="ft" id="ft" 
                 type="text" onBlur="checkAvailability()" ><span id="user-
                 availability-status"></span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" 
              value="add" class="btn btn-success" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                              </div> <!-- /content --> 
                         </div><!-- /x-panel --> 
                        </div> <!-- /col --> 
                        </div> <!-- /row --> 
                            </div>
                            </div> <!-- /.col-right --> 
                                       <!-- /page content -->


                  <?php $this->load->view('admin/partials/admin_footer'); ?>


                 <?php if($this->session->flashdata('message') != NULL) : ?>
                    <script>
                 swal({
               title: "Success",
                text: "<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message'); ?>",
                     type: "success",
                        timer: 1500,
                                showConfirmButton: false
                                 });
                           </script>
                            <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: you should put your code separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function do_upload()
{
     $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
     $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
     $config['max_size']             = 100;
     $config['max_width']            = 1024;
     $config['max_height']           = 768;
     $this->load->library('upload', $config);

     if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
     {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
     }
     else
     {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
     }
}
```

for more detail see:[upload file with codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 
        enctype="multipart/form-data" 
on your form tag and also remove the `</form>` just after the image input box.

Answer (score 0):

```
Controller:

$doc_1 = "uploads/img_1/";
if (isset($_FILES['userfile_1']) && !empty($_FILES['userfile_1'])) {
    $filename = pathinfo($_FILES['userfile_1']['name']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile_1']['tmp_name'], $doc_1.$filename['basename'])) {
        $attch_1 = base_url().$doc_1.$filename['basename'];
    }
    else {
        $attch_1 = "na";
    }
}
```

view:

```
 <?php echo form_open_multipart("store_property",  ['class'=>'form-horizontal']); ?>

<input type="file" name="userfile_1" />
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.